# How to handle partial failure of Inter Microservices Communication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

We have micro services which communicate with other micro services. I need to handle scenarios where a service is down might be because of a failure or for maintenance, or the service might be overloaded and responding extremely slowly to requests.

In this scenario, I would like to retry after some scheduled time. How can I achieve that ? What are the possible options ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169046/how-to-manage-microservice-failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every microservice should implement and expose health checks. Frameworks like Spring boot provide a readymade way to do that. Even though your microservices could check whether the target service is UP by directly checking the health endpoint and sleeping and retrying, in practice you will use a framework such as hystrix or Spring retry for that.

[Spring retry](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-retry-way-to-handle-failures) for example allows you to define different backoff policies for retrying a certain action and also lets you define recovery action based on response codes

There are also number of other frameworks such as Spring cloud which provides many patterns to achieve High Availability by maintaining a service registry - having HA will let you avoid having to retry in the first place.

For HA, an approach would also be to have at-least 2 instances of each service and use a LB like nginx in front of that. In this case, LB could route traffic to the healthy instance. This way you are delegating the responsibility of finding a healthy node to LB.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Spring boot admin. it will show you the service status whether it is up or running.

```
1) in order to check with HTTP you can try Feign Client.
2) for retry you can  implements Retryer and add custo
```

m logic